# Overcoming lack of SocketUtils in Spring Boot 3

Tags: spring, spring-boot, wiremock

I'm preparing to the migration of a Spring Boot service to Spring Boot 3 (I'm trying version `3.0.0-RC1`) and unfortunately I'm facing the lack of `SocketUtils` that has been removed.

This means that some libraries that I'm using for testing (e.g. [WireMock](https://wiremock.org/)) don't work. I'm following [Introduce TestSocketUtils as a replacement for SocketUtils #28210](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/28210) hoping it will resume some tests that currently fail to load.

Do you know some workarounds or other tools I can use in the meanwhile to test the service at the API layer?

Comment: Could you provide more details regarding the issue. As far as I know WireMock has no dependencies to Spring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was hitting the same issue causing this exception:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/util/SocketUtils

The fix for me was to upgrade the spring-cloud-contract-wiremock dependency to 4.0.0-M5.

I also had to add this into my pom as the version wasn't available otherwise:

```
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>spring-milestones</id>
      <name>Spring Milestones</name>
      <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

I didn't try any earlier versions to see where the fix was introduced, but you can find them here:
https://repo.spring.io/ui/native/milestone/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-contract-wiremock/